# What does it mean for git to render a file in red in terminal?

Tags: git, terminal

I cannot post images for I am newbie here, sorry.

The situation is as I `ls` files in the repo in terminal, some of them appeared red while I don't know what does it mean.
The red-highlighted file is neither deleted nor untracked. The coloring is consistent in both bash and zsh so I assume the git package caused it. However I cannot find documentations talking about this. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you came across this red highlighted file?  What git operation were you doing when it happened?  It could be a merge conflict.

Comment: I was simply `ls` -ing files in the repo. A merge conflict... umm it is possible, but the highlighting does not go away as I update(with no other people touching it) the file again and even again.

Comment: If the *standard* `ls` shell command (which is not aware of git) colors the file listing red it means the filesystem is (well, files are) 'in a questionable state'. Run fsck and check the files, properties of, and permissions themselves. If using `git-ls`, please indicate that.

Comment: Type `git status` in the same location and let us know what you see.

Comment: `ls` has nothing to do with git. If running `ls` is only coloring files red in a repo then `git` must have done something to affect the files to cause `ls` to _independently_ color the files red.

Comment: Thanks for all that help. Yes only some files in this repo are colored red. Runing `git status`gives `On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean`.

Comment: This still leaves open the question of why the files are colored red, but it would seem that `git` is not the cause of it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Credits to all the guys helped by commenting the question, pointing out that that shouldn't have been caused by `git`, and that there is something that caused `ls` to behave in that way.

The answer is those red-files were files that was granted high permissions (755) by some teammate and my shells decided to show it in that way. Surprise!

Regrettably enough though, I still cannot find documentations talking about this feature. Thanks again for people gave their help and I hope this would help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in question an [archive file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_file) (for example, a [tar file](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTar_%2528computing%2529&ei=-TFtVbyaCpeeyASpnoGgAw&usg=AFQjCNFq56NFGZtpRsyo5Rbp9SfxJmzYsw&sig2=nmiHRwg8eAGWONO_cHuY8A))?

As you can see from this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal), in bash, a file displayed in red as an output of `ls` is typically an archive file.

In any case, running `ls` has absolutely nothing to do with `git`, and must have something to do with the type of shell you're running and how it's configured.